# Most efficient way to retrieve a sub-query COUNT grouped by top table?

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure-sql-database, query-performance

Given the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE categories
(
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
    name NVARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE [group]
(
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE logger
(
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
    group_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    uuid CHAR(17)
);

CREATE TABLE data
(
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
    logger_uuid CHAR(17),
    category_name NVARCHAR(50),
    recorded_on DATETIME
);
```

And the following rules

1. Each `data` record references a `logger` and a `category`
2. Each `logger` will always have a `group`
3. Each `group` can have multiple `logger`s
4. I only want to count the *most recent* data recorded

`category_name` isn't unique per row, it's just a way to associate a given data record under a category, `id` is really just a surrogate key.

What would be the optimum way to achieve the a resultset like

```
category_id | logger_group_count
--------------------------------
12345          4
67890          2
.....          ...
```

i.e. count the no. of groups for each category where a logger has recorded data?

As an initial stab I came up with:

```
SELECT g.id, COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id)) AS logger_group_count 
FROM categories g
  LEFT OUTER JOIN data d ON d.category_name = g.name
  INNER JOIN logger s ON s.uuid = d.logger_uuid
  INNER JOIN group a ON a.id = s.group_id
GROUP BY g.id
```

But is *extremely* slow (~45s), `data` has 400k+ records - here's the [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryvtJ0Hwz) and here's a [fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=393a5452180f594483a4b94371139d1c) to play with.

I want to make sure I'm eeking the most out of the query before I start looking at other things i.e. hardware utilization etc. Azure SQL costs can go up substantially (even though you maybe just need a little more juice off your current tier).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been **[moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73345/discussion-on-question-by-james-most-efficient-way-to-retrieve-a-sub-query-count)**. Use that chat room for further troubleshooting and be sure to keep the question body up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a great answer from @JoeObbish I was better able to understand the query plan and work out where it was struggling and what indexes I could use to improve it. In between this, the goal posts did change a little as I forgot to mention that I needed this to only be applicable to the *latest* reading from each logger e.g. if `logger_a` recorded data under `category_x @ 11:50` and `category_y @ 11:51` I would only want to count this as `category_y`.

Here's the resultant SQL

```
;WITH logger_data AS (
  SELECT 
    category_name,
    logger_uuid,
    recorded_on,
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY logger_uuid ORDER BY recorded_on DESC)
  FROM data
)
SELECT c.id, count(DISTINCT l.group_id) FROM categories c
INNER JOIN logger_data d on d.category_name = c.name
INNER JOIN logger l ON l.uuid = d.logger_uuid
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY c.id
```

This is still an expensive query, however, with the following indexes applied

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_latest ON "dbo"."data"
(
    logger_uuid,
    recorded_on DESC
)
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_groups ON "dbo"."logger"
(
    group_id
)
```

Goes from ~25s to ~3s and for a table with ~500k rows. Pretty happy with this, I think there is probably more room for improvement but as it stands this is good enough.

Here is the final [plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJRioOKDG), any other suggestions / improvements welcome.

Answer (score 8):

You're on a newer version of SQL Server so the actual plan gives you a lot of information. See the caution sign on the `SELECT` operator? That means that SQL Server generated a warning which could affect query performance. You should always look at those:

```
<Warnings>
<PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Seek Plan" Expression="[s].[logger_uuid]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nchar(17),[d].[uuid],0)" />
<PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Seek Plan" Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(100),[d].[name],0)=[g].[name]" />
</Warnings>
```

There are two data type conversions caused by your schema. Based on the warnings I suspect that name is actually an `NVARCHAR(100)` and `logger_uuid` is an `NCHAR(17)`. The posted table schema in the question may not be correct. You should understand the root cause of why these conversions are happening and fix it. Some types of data type conversions prevent index seeks, lead to cardinality estimate issues, and cause other problems.

Another important thing to check is wait stats. You can see those in the details of the `SELECT` operator as well. Here's the XML for your wait stats and the time spent by the query:

```
<WaitStats>
<Wait WaitType="RESOURCE_GOVERNOR_IDLE" WaitTimeMs="49515" WaitCount="3773" />
<Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="57164" WaitCount="2466" />
</WaitStats>
<QueryTimeStats ElapsedTime="67135" CpuTime="10007" />
```

I'm not a cloud guy but it looks like your query isn't able to [fully engage a CPU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/04/10/what-is-resource_governor_idle-and-why-you-should-not-ignore-it-completely/). That's probably related to your current Azure tier. The query only needed about 10 seconds of CPU when executing but it took 67 seconds. I believe that 50 seconds of that time was spent being throttled and 7 seconds of that time was given to you but used on other queries that were concurrently running. The bad news is that the query is slower than it could be due to your tier. The good news it that any reductions in CPU could lead to a 5X reduction in run time. In other words, if you can get the query to use 1 second of CPU then you might see a runtime of around 5 seconds.

Next you can look at the Actual Time Statistics property in your operator details to see where the CPU time was spent. Your plan uses row mode so the CPU time for an operator is the sum of time spent by that operator as well as its children. This is a relatively simple plan so it doesn't take long to discover that the clustered index scan on `logger_data` uses 6527 ms of CPU time. The loop join that calls it uses 10006 ms of CPU time, so all of your query's CPU is spent at that step. Another clue that something is going wrong at that step can be found by looking at the thickness of the relative arrows:

[image: thick arrows]

A lot of rows are returned from that operator so it's worth looking at detail. Looking at the actual number of rows for the clustered index scan you can see that 14088885 rows were returned and 14100798 rows were read. However, the table cardinality is just 484803 rows. Intuitively that seems pretty inefficient, right? The clustered index scan returns far more than the number of rows in the table. Some other plan with a different join type or access method on the table is likely to be more efficient.

Why did SQL Server read and return so many rows? The clustered index is on the inner side of a nested loop. There are 38 rows returned by the outer side of the loop (the scan on the `logger` table) so the scan on `logger_data` executes 38 times. 484803*38 = 18422514 which is pretty close to the number of rows read. So why did SQL Server choose such a plan that feels so inefficient? It even estimates that it'll do 57 scans of the table, so arguably the plan that you got was more efficient than it suspected.

You might have been wondering why there's a `TOP` operator in your plan. SQL Server introduced a [row goal](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/18/inside-the-optimiser-row-goals-in-depth.aspx) to when creating a query plan for your query. This might be more detail than you want, but the short version is that SQL Server does not always need to return all rows from a clustered index scan. Sometimes it can stop early if it only needs a fixed number of rows and it finds those rows before it reaches the end of the scan. A scan isn't as expensive if it can stop early so the operator cost is [discounted by a formula](https://orderbyselectnull.com/2017/10/19/a-row-goal-request/) when a row goal is present. In other words, SQL Server expects to scan the clustered index 57 times, but it thinks that it will find the single row that it needs very quickly. It only needs a single row from each scan due to the presence of the `TOP` operator.

You can make your query faster by encouraging the query optimizer to pick a plan that doesn't scan the `logger_data` table 38 times. This might be as simple as eliminating the data type conversions. That could allow SQL Server to do an index seek instead of a scan. If not, fix the conversions and create a covering index for the `logger_data`:

```
CREATE INDEX IX ON logger_data (category_name, logger_uuid);
```

The query optimizer chooses a plan based on cost. Adding this index makes it unlikely to get the slow plan which does many scans on logger_data because it'll be cheaper to access the table through an index seek instead of a clustered index scan.

If you aren't able to add the index you can consider adding a query hint to disable the introduction of row goals: `USE HINT('DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL'))`. You should only do this if you feel comfortable with the concept of row goals and understand them. Adding that hint should result in a different plan, but I can't say how efficient it'll be.

Answer (score 4):

Start by ensuring each table has all candidate keys declared, and foreign keys enforced:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.categories
(
    id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [UQ dbo.categories id]
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED,
    [name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT [PK dbo.categories name]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

-- Choose a better name for this table
CREATE TABLE dbo.[group]
(
    id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [PK dbo.group id]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.logger
(
    id uniqueidentifier 
        CONSTRAINT [UQ dbo.logger id]
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED,
    group_id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [FK dbo.group id]
        FOREIGN KEY (group_id)
        REFERENCES [dbo].[group] (id),
    uuid char(17) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [PK dbo.logger uuid]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.logger_data
(
    id uniqueidentifier 
        CONSTRAINT [PK dbo.logger_data id]
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    logger_uuid char(17) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [FK dbo.logger_data uuid]
        FOREIGN KEY (logger_uuid)
        REFERENCES dbo.logger (uuid),
    category_name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [dbo.logger_data name]
        FOREIGN KEY (category_name)
        REFERENCES dbo.categories ([name]),
    recorded_on datetime NOT NULL,

    INDEX [dbo.logger_data logger_uuid recorded_on] 
        CLUSTERED (logger_uuid, recorded_on)
);
```

I have also added a non-unique clustered index to `logger_data` on `logger_uuid, recorded_on`.

Then notice the biggest task in your execution plan is the scan of the 484,836 rows in the data table. Since you are only interested in the most recent reading for a particular logger, and there are only 48 loggers currently, it is more efficient to replace that full scan with 48 singleton seeks:

```
SELECT 
    category_id = C.id, 
    logger_group_count = COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT L.group_id)
FROM dbo.logger AS L
CROSS APPLY 
(
    -- Latest reading per logger
    SELECT TOP (1) 
        LD.recorded_on,
        LD.category_name
    FROM  dbo.logger_data AS LD
    WHERE LD.logger_uuid = L.uuid
    ORDER BY 
        LD.recorded_on DESC
) AS LDT1
JOIN dbo.categories AS C
    ON C.[name] = LDT1.category_name
GROUP BY
    C.id
ORDER BY
    C.id;
```

The execution plan is:

[image: Estimated plan]

[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=360a1a683ef30d0c51c2cde2798c1a08)

You should also patch your instance from 2017 RTM to the latest cumulative update.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the join on Group?

Why is Categories g?

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(DISTINCT(s.group_id)) AS logger_group_count 
FROM categories c
JOIN data d 
  ON d.category_name = c.name
JOIN logger s 
  ON s.uuid = d.logger_uuid
GROUP BY c.id
```

I hope in real life you are declaring the foreign keys.

You should have an index on each of those join columns.

Answer (score 0):

Problem areas are :

1. `Improper data type` :If data type is `INT` that means less data page and no `index fragmentation`, if it is  `NewSequentialID` that means `more data page` and `no index fragmentation`, with `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` you get both problem.So INT data type is ideal choice.
2. `Data type and length of both column should be same in relationship column` : for example,  `a.category_name = g.NAME`  Logger_data Clustered index scan in plan suggest both column length should be 50 or 100,so that Optimizer do not have to spend time doing `Convert_Implicit`
   Even better,  relationship should be define with int data type like CategoryID int`.
3. If this query is very important and frequently use then you can think of `Denormalization`,in your example I can't say how ?

Try below query,

```
    SELECT g.id
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN rn = 1
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END)
FROM categories g
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT d.category_name
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY d.category_name
            ,s.group_id ORDER BY s.group_id
            ) rn
    FROM data d
    INNER JOIN logger s ON s.uuid = d.logger_uuid
        --INNER JOIN [group] a ON a.id = s.group_id
    ) a ON a.category_name = g.NAME
GROUP BY g.id
```

I like `@Paparazzi` idea so I have incorporated it.

I think plan is better than your.
With above correction and index tuning it will perform even better.

you need to correct here,

```
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by d.category_name,a.id order by s.group_id )rn
```

`order by s.group_id` , it should be `order by DateOrIDcolumn desc` which give latest record.with your sample I am not able to make out how to find latest record.

Also notice   `partition by d.category_name` this should have been `partition by d.CatgoryID`.